# pnpm not found private organization package

Tags: reactjs, github, npm-publish, npm-package, pnpm

I've published a private package on the organization level. package publish successfully. now I'm trying to install that private package into my other repository.

when I'm trying installing that package using npm it's installing successfully. but my project is set up through pnpm. so I'm trying to install that private package through pnpm. but with pnpm I getting the below error.

[image]

```
https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@xyzscope/dark-ui/1.0.0/<hash>error (ERR_PNPM_FETCH_409). Will retry in 10 seconds. 2 retries left.
```

.npmrc

```
@xyzscope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}

save-exact=true
engine-strict=true
```

Comment: 409? I do not see any ERR_PNPM_FETCH error with 409 ([search pnpm](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apnpm%2Fpnpm+ERR_PNPM_FETCH&type=code)).

Comment: @VonC, I've updated the issue. see the screenshot above.

Comment: Strange. Do you have the latest version of pnpm?

Comment: yes, latest version install in system 8.3.1

Comment: it's working with npm but not works with pnpm.